# Why does my internet connection only work properly with a UDP-based VPN?

Tags: networking, router, internet, tcp, udp

My house is connected to the main router in another building via a single LAN cable that is run partially underground, partially outside (along the wall of the house). There is one switch on the route, that also connects other parts of the main building which do not experience problems. So far, so non-optimal, but surprisingly it worked out for a long time.

Since a few days ago, internet speed in my house has dropped dramatically, to around 2 Mbps. I have confirmed that speed in the main building is still at ~50 Mbps, as expected. Interestingly, (a) upload speed is unaffected and (b) this drop in speed goes away when turning on a UDP-based VPN (I get ~24 Mbps). Recently, other parts of the main building have been added to the network via one previously unused LAN slot in the router.

This discrepancy and the recent changes to the network makes me suspect that the problem is not purely hardware-based. Can any conclusions be drawn from this strange behavior that would help me in troubleshooting before going out and replacing each piece of hardware step by step? Replacing the LAN cable would be difficult, and I want to rule out all other possible issues.

Comment: Do you have access to the main router? Do all kinds of UDP-based VPNs work, or are you testing only one specific protocol? Do TCP-based VPNs also have performance issues? Can you check if the affected TCP connections have any packet loss (statistics in netstat, retransmissions in wireshark)?

Comment: I have access to the main router (soft- and hardware), yes. I only have one VPN provider (NordVPN), which I use through Ubuntu's OpenVPN. They provide UDP- and TCP-based configuration files, and the UDP-based ones work (I have tested ~5), while the TCP-based ones are slow. I have netstat and wireshark, but very little experience in interpreting their results, so more guidance to check for errors there would be very welcome.

Comment: Run a capture on your physical interface, filtering for the VPN's TCP port, look for packets that are highlighted as retransmissions, or those with the RST flag, or fragmented, or whole reconnections... anything that jumps out.

Comment: Thank you, I am away for a couple of days, but will try this when I come back and update post accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The only conclusion from the above data, is for me that the new additions
to the network have caused the problems. The new demands seem to be
connected to downloading data, so it might be that some of the new user(s)
are doing heavy downloading (or torrenting).
For some reason connected to the router's hardware and/or software,
this only affects your part of the building.

Troubleshooting advice:

- Disconnect the new port from the router and see if the problem
  has disappeared. This will confirm that part as being the problem.
- Change the order of the ports on the router, for example exchange
  your connecting port with the new-comer's port.
  This will tell if the new port has some kind of priority over your port.
- Update the router's firmware to the latest version.
- Verify the router's priority settings, and especially that of QoS.
  If you have a Netgear router, do the opposite of
  [How do I enable upstream QoS on my NETGEAR router?](https://kb.netgear.com/23852/How-do-I-enable-upstream-quality-of-service-QoS-to-optimize-gaming-on-my-Nighthawk-router)

Comment: The problem is not related to heavy usage - I have checked with the people in the new building part, and overall usage in the main router is also low (no one in the network is a heavy user). Disconnecting them temporarily has not changed anything. The router is updated, and the only thing being prioritized by the router (a Fritz!Box, as we are in Germany) is VoIP - but as I said, I don't think it's a usage problem. Things are fine when I connect directly in the main building, both via LAN and WLAN.

Comment: Could you add more details in your post as to when this happens and what kind of connection you have (there seem to be two kinds). A schema of the network setup would help. Some details regarding the hardware, such as the router's model, will also help.

Comment: Thanks, I will update the post with more details when I am back. The router is a AVM FRITZ!Box 7590. I probably won't be able to draw the full network, as it is a mess that has grown over 20 years, and no one ever bothered to document which cable that disappears in the wall goes where "because it works now".